# Как получить индекс блока по которому был клик?

Tags: javascript

Есть 4 блока с классом .hide
Я получаю массив с этими блоками через querySelectorAll('.hide')
Мне нужно узнать индекс блока по которому был сделан клик, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем вопросе не хватает примера кода и информации что не получается.
Один из вариантов:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.hide').forEach((e,i)=>{
  e.addEventListener('click', ()=>console.log(i))
})
```

```html
<div class="hide">HIDE</div>
<div class="hide">HIDE</div>
<div class="hide">HIDE</div>
<div class="hide">HIDE</div>
```

Comment: Только html коллекция которую возвращает querySelectorAll поддерживает метод forEach не так давно, поэтому на более старых браузерах будут проблемы. Лучше сразу преобразовать коллекцию в массив

Comment: @fortavey как сказать [не так давно](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_nodelist_foreach) Safari 10 (2016 год), chrome 51 (2017 год), это тоже самое что не использовать `flexbox`. Поддержка по миру  92.46%, Украина 89%, Россия 79.59%.

Comment: Как по мне то 92% это так себе показатель. Я встречал заказчиков которые сами пользуются старыми браузерами. И попробуй ему объясни что это он олень которых в нашем мире мало. Не работает и все! Поэтому проще предотвратить проблему. Не так уж и сложно написать что то типа Array.prototype.slice.call и не парится по поводу даже самых старых браузеров

Comment: И на `table` сайт сверстать вместо grid/flex так как 8% это же ЦА :) Для этого давно придумали Полифил, чтоб забыть про 8%

Comment: При чем сдесь ЦА? Нужно понимать уровень разработчиков которые задают здесь вопросы. Большинство понятия не имеют что такое полифил, бабель и даже автопрефиксер. Они пишут стрелочные функции потому что так модно и все здесь так делают. А завтра получат по шапке от заказчика потому что у него дома на компьютере или на старом андроид телефоне ничего не работает.

Comment: @fortavey ЦА к тому, что опять таки на примере верстки вместо грида и флекса писать только на блоках так как поддержка даже флекса в Росии 83.56%, CSS Variables 80.92% (с префиксами) и тут ни один полифил не поможет. Только блок и флот, только хардкор. Так чтоли? Я всегда с заказчиками обговариваю этот момент, да и часто у заказчиков уже в ТЗ стоят версии, так как для IE писать костыли это + время = допкост